# PHP - Parse, Read XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong with parsing/reading an `xml` document.
My guess is that it's not standardized, and I'm going to need a different process to read anything from the string.

If that's the case, then I'm rather excited to learn how someone would read the xml.
Here's what I've got, and what I'm doing.

**example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="someurl.php"?>
<response>
 <status>Error</status>
 <error>The error message I need to extract, if the status says Error</error>
</response>
```

**read_xml.php**

```
<?php
 $content = 'example.xml';
 $string = file_get_contents($content);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
 print_r($xml);
?>
```

I'm getting no result back from the `print_r`.
I switched the `xml` to something more standard, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

...and it worked fine.  So I'm sure it's due to a non-standard format, passed back from the source I'm getting it from.

How would I extract the `<status>` and `<error>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tek has a good answer, but if you want to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), you can try something like this:

```
<?php  

$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
echo $xml->asXML(); // this will print the whole string
echo $xml->status; // print status
echo $xml->error; // print error

?>
```

EDIT: If you have multiple `<status>` and `<error>` tags in your XML, have a look at this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
foreach($xml->status as $status){
    echo $status;
}
foreach($xml->error as $error){
    echo $error;
}
```

I'm assuming `<response>` is your root. If it isn't, try `$xml->response->status` and `$xml->response->error`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use PHP's DOMDocument class better.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="someurl.php"?>
<response>
 <status>Error</status>
 <error>The error message I need to extract, if the status says Error</error>
</response>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$statuses = $dom->getElementsByTagName('status');
foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    echo "The status tag says: " . $status->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mID6Hp